# How to correctly set base_path for Symfony asset() that sits inside my custom bundle in vendor?

Tags: css, symfony

So I know how to define a package name for this case:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('test.css', 'my_custom_bundle') }}">
```

To make `my_custom_bundle` be recognisable I have to go to:

```
framework:
  assets:
    packages:
```

and define my custom one like:

```
framework:
  assets:
    packages:
      my_custom_bundle:
        base_path: [HERE I HAVE TO POINT TO VENDOR]
```

I don't know what to put into `base_path`. My `css` file and every other asset is made in a custom bundle that is shared and pulled through composer.

It sits in:
`/vendor/my-company/my-custom-bundle/src/Foo/Bar/Baz/Resources/styles/test.css`

How I should set the `base_path`? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's impossible since `vendor` is not and should not be a publicly accessible directory. I would have to do a symlink from `public` and start the reference from there…

Please correct me if I'm wrong.